# Checking the value of a node in firebase and adding to datab

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I need to write code that looks at the value at notifications/notifications_switch. If the value at this key is 1, I need to add a new node to the test_manav node. I'm confused as to whether I should accomplish this with the code I currently have written(the second snippet), by using ref.key, and then checking the value of the key, or whether i should use:

```
ref.on('value', function(snapshot){
   if(snapshot.val()==1){
```

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1000 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  var db = admin.database().ref().child('test_manav');
  var ref = admin.database().ref('/notifications/notifications_switch');
  var key = ref.key;
  if(key==1){
      return db.update({
        time: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        test: 'Hello Manav'
      });
    }
});
```

[image: Picture of Database]

Comment: Do you have to do this update only once or do you want to continually listen to the value at notifications/notifications_switch?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I have to listen for the value every 1000 minutes which is why im using the pubsub function

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [read the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) at the location [a single time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once) using [once('value')](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once).

Your function should also [return a promise after all the asynchronous work is complete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

Comment: the read the database link isn't working, do you have another link?

Comment: It's the same as the second link, but without a named anchor in the url.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1000 minutes').onRun((context) => {
    const db = admin.database();
    const targetRef = db.ref('test_manav');
    const switchRef = db.ref('notifications_switch');

    return switchRef.once('value')   // <-- See the return here
        .then(dataSnapshot => {
            if (dataSnapshot.val() === 1) {
                return targetRef.update({     // <-- See the return here
                    time: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                    test: 'Hello Manav'
                });
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        });
});
```

---

As explained by Doug in his answer:

1. You should use the `once()` method;
2. You must return a Promise when the asynchronous tasks are finished by returning the Promises chain.